# Ordernar lista de registros por año Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

He estado ordenando los registros según ciertas fechas, pero que sucede si quiero hacerlo todo generalizado por fechas, es decir ordenarlo por fechas q bastaria por ejemplo con un `@object.order.("extract(year from created_at) DESC").each` bien, esto lo ordena por año, los registros los muestro con un `ul > li`, pero como puedo hacer, para que me los ordene por filas, es decir, primera fila año tal, segunda fila año tal y en cada fila muestre los registros de cada año? Que exista un salto de linea por cada año.

Comment: por favor edita el mensaje para que sea legible. Añade espacios y formatea como código lo debido

Comment: Gracias Hcarrera pero ya solucione el problema eliminare el post

Comment: O lo dejare ya q abajo dan solucion q alguien podria ocupar

Comment: Si, mejor dejalo. El propósito de StackOverflow es crear una base de datos donde mucha gente pueda venir y solucionar sus problemas. Es por ello que es importante que tus mensajes sean legibles, para que ayuden a mucha gente. Por favor, considera formatearlo correctamente aunque ya haya solucionado tu problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar group_by . Si el modelo fuera user

```
User.order("extract(year from created_at) DESC").group_by{|user| user.created_at.year}.each do |year, users| 
  puts year.to_s
  users.each do |user|
    puts user.name.to_s
  end
end
```

Comment: Va genial Vitomd! Te agradezco mucho!